# Expo who remained longest with the Nationals

Tags: baseball, trivia

Which Expo player who moved to the Nationals in 2005 remained longest (continuously) with the Nationals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comparing the [2004 Expos opening day roster](http://www.baseball-almanac.com/teamstats/roster.php?y=2004&t=MON) with the [2009 Nationals opening day roster](http://www.baseball-almanac.com/teamstats/roster.php?y=2009&t=WS0), it looks like [Nick Johnson](http://www.baseball-almanac.com/players/player.php?p=johnsni01) is the winner here.  He joined the Expos in 2004, and stayed with the Nationals until 2009.  I think [Luis Ayala](http://www.baseball-almanac.com/players/player.php?p=ayalalu01) comes in 2nd place, as he stayed until 2008.

[Livan Hernandez](http://www.baseball-almanac.com/players/player.php?p=hernali01) stayed with the Nationals until 2006, then came back from 2009-2011.